# SQL complex select statement in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, join

I have 3 tables in my database;

```
InfoTable,
FriendTable,
UsersTable
```

and these are their columns:

**InfoTable**

```
Uid int,
Username varchar(256),
Address varchar(256),
```

**FriendTable**

```
Fid int,
UserName varchar(256),
FriendUserName varchar(256),
Status varchar(10)---Default value:'false'
```

**UsersTable**

```
Uid int,
FirstName varchar(256),
LastName varchar(256),
Username varchar(256)
```

I have to achieve all information of friends of that username. I am getting using this query,

```
SELECT * 
FROM InfoTable 
WHERE username IN 
     (SELECT FriendUserName  
      FROM FriendTable  
      WHERE username = @UserName AND status='true')
```

Now I have to add his/her FirstName and LastName from users table in the same query.
How can I achieve this in one complete query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT friend.*
from InfoTable info 
inner join FriendTable friend on info.username=friend.FriendUserName
--inner join UsersTable user1 on info.Uid=user1.Uid 
--(In case you want columns from UsersTable)
where info.username=@UserName 
friend.status='true'
```

Here is good article for **[JOIN](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT info.*, frnd.*, usr.*
from InfoTable info
INNER join FriendTable frnd on frnd.FriendUserName = info.username
INNER join usersTable usr on usr.Uid=info.Uid
```

This will give you all details of all table. And you can add your conditions in the above query like ( `and frnd.username=@UserName and frnd.status='true'`).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a `join` query like

```
select i.*,f.*,u.* from infitable as i  join friendtable as f
on i.username = f.friendusername join usertable as u on i.uid = u.uid
where i.username=@UserName and
f.status='true';
```

Here i am selecting all tables value you can select as per your own need.

For Knowledge about `joins` [Click Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
SELECT it.*, ut.FirstName, ut.LastName
FROM InfoTable it
     LEFT OUTER JOIN UsersTable ut
          ON it.Uid = ut.Uid
WHERE it.username IN 
     (SELECT FriendUserName  
      FROM FriendTable  
      WHERE username = @UserName AND status='true')
```